# excel embedded in winform with Windows API

Tags: c#, .net, excel, winforms, office-automation

my code:

```
  public void ImplantFile1(IntPtr hwnd, string fileName = "")
        {
            try
            {
                MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, 0, 0, 0, true);
                SetParent(hwnd, this.Handle.ToInt32());
                int top = -40;
                if (Tool.IsSuffixFile(fileName, Const.Suffix_Excel))
                {
                    top = -40;
                }
                else if (Tool.IsSuffixFile(fileName, Const.Suffix_Word))
                {
                    top = -32;
                }
                MoveWindow(hwnd, 0, top, this.Bounds.Width, this.Bounds.Height + Math.Abs(top), true);
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            { }
        }
```

callback function:

```
ImplantFile1(Excel.Application.IntPtr ,"C:\cool.xlsx");
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXdUw.png)

Excel successfully embedded in winform！when i set

```
ExcelApp.EnableEvents = true;
```

Clicking the cell does not respond！